# Transitive property causes infinite loop in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Assume a bunch of categories, and items in those categories. Some categories are synonyms of others. For example, mobile_phone and cell_phone. Given the rules `syn(mobile_phone, cell_phone).` and `is_a(iphone, cell_phone).`, I need a call to `is_a(iphone, mobile_phone).` to return true even though that rule doesn't exist in the knowledge base.

Here's what I have:

```
is_syn('antibiotics' , 'antineoplastics').

is_a('mitomycin', 'antibiotics').
is_a('doxorubicin liposomal', 'antineoplastics').
is_a('idarubicin', 'antineoplastics').
is_a('pentostatin', 'antibiotics').

syn(X, Y) :-
   (  is_syn(Y, X)
   ;  is_syn(X, Y)
   ).

is_a(X, Y) :-
   syn(Y, Z),
   is_a(X, Z).
```

Comment: You should add your facts explicitly, so the problem is reproducible.

Comment: Added a snippet. To be clear, it is getting output, but loops over the same output over and over.

Comment: This example does reproduce the error I observe. As for the phones... well that was just for clarity, of course. Try a query of `is_a('idarubicin', X).` It returns antineoplastics endlessly. Worse yet is a query like `is_a(something, X).` Which loops endlessly without any output at all.

Comment: And BTW, with the example as it is at the moment, don't you get compiler warnings?

Comment: Only that there are discontiguous definitions of is_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
is_syn('antibiotics' , 'antineoplastics').

fact_is_a('mitomycin', 'antibiotics').
fact_is_a('doxorubicin liposomal', 'antineoplastics').
fact_is_a('idarubicin', 'antineoplastics').
fact_is_a('pentostatin', 'antibiotics').

syn(X,X). % So we don't lose the obvious facts.
syn(X, Y) :-
   (  is_syn(Y, X)
   ;  is_syn(X, Y)
   ).

is_a(X, Y) :-  
    syn(X,S),
    fact_is_a(S,Z),
    syn(Z,Y). % Returns all synonyms of Z

is_a(X, Y) :- % Does the transitive part of is_a
    syn(X,S),
    fact_is_a(S,Z),
    is_a(Z,Y).
```

I think the problem you had was such a stack:

```
[1] is_a(V1,Y)
[1] syn(V1, V2)
[2] is_a(V2, Y)
[2] syn(V2, V1)
[3] is_a(V1,Y)
```

Back to where we started.

It could be possible to achieve the same as this without calling facts something different ( which would be much more elegant ). If you do reach a point like that, please post it because I'd love to see it.

Comment: This works perfectly. Unfortunately this project has a pretty significant time crunch and likely no one will ever see this part of the code so it doesn't really matter all that much what it looks like.